# Usar como PartialView una vista de un controlador ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Resulta que en el `_layout` tengo lo que se va a mostrar siempre en todas las paginas, resulta que queria sacar la barra de navegación del `_layout` por que quiero implementar el log out ahi

Tengo el controlador y el metodo del navbar asi:

```
public class NavController : Controller
    {
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult navbar()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

En el _layout estoy implementado esto:

```
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("navbar", "Nav");
    }
```

pero cuando la pagina carga, me dice esto:

**

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. No se encuentra el controlador
>   de la ruta de acceso '/Home/Index' o no implementa IController.

**

En que esta fallando, y como puedo hacer para que tome como partial el "`navbar.cshtml`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action es el metodo que estas buscando
`@Html.Action("navbar", "Nav")`
y si tienes tu vista parcial en otro lugar puedes asegurarte usando el siguiente metodo.

`return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_PartialNavBar.cshtml", objResultado);`

Answer (score 1):

Al devolver la Vista parcial desde la Acción del Controlador, indica el **nombre** de la Vista en el método `PartialView()`.

Para seguir las nomenclaturas MVC, deberías renombrar la Vista parcial a `_Navbar.cshtml`, y asegurarte que está situada en la carpeta `/Views/Shared/` (donde se encuentra `_Layout.cshtml`).

```
public class NavController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult navbar()
    {
        return PartialView("_Navbar");
    }
}
```

En lo que respecta a la llamada a la Vista parcial:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("navbar", "Nav"); }
```

Parece estar todo correcto.

Si el error continúa, podría ser un problema de Rutas. Deberías indicar en la pregunta tu archivo de rutas **`RouteConfig.cs`**.